# HTML button loop

Tags: html, codeigniter

Hello guys i'm trying to figure out how can I add more textboxes by clicking an add button.

I'm using codeigniter framework so here is my view:

```
<form action="save_new_inventorytype" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add New Inventory Type</legend>
        <label id="lbl_tablename" name="lbl_tablename">Inventory Type Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txt_tablename" name="txt_tablename" size="30" /><br>
        <label id="lbl_columns" name="lbl_columns" style="position: absolute; top: 276px;">Column Name:</label>
        <label style="position: absolute; top: 276px; left: 352px;">Type:</label>
        <label style="position: absolute; top: 276px; left: 565px;">Length/Values:</label><br>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="txt_columnname" name="txt_columnname" size="30"/>&nbsp;
        <select id="cbo_columntype" name="cbo_columntype" style="width: 200px;">
            <option>INT</option>
            <option>VARCHAR</option>
            <option>TEXT</option>
            <option>DATE</option>
        </select>&nbsp;
        <input type="text" id="txt_columnlength" name="txt_columnlength"     size="30"/>&nbsp;
        <button type="button" class="btn_plusvalue btn-success btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button><br>
        <br>
        <button type="button" class="btn_addtable btn-success btn-sm" id="btn_addtable" name="btn_addtable">Save Inventory Type</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn_canceltable btn-danger btn-sm">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn_cleartable btn-warning btn-sm">Clear</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Here is a print screen of my view: [image]
I want to have those three(textbox,combobox,textbox) to duplicate when I click on that plus button.
Can anyone help me on this one? Please? I know that I have to use loop but I don't know how.

Comment: Take a look at `JavaScript`

Comment: can you use jquery? or do you need only javascript solution?

Comment: @krupalshah: I think a javascript solution will do..

Comment: @eljon_i3 sorry, I have jquery solution for this...Do you want it? then I will try in answer.

Comment: I have answered your question..hope it may help you..this is only possible using jquery or javascript DOM model. search on google for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have `jquery` solution for adding textbox on click of button. try something like this:

Suppose, you have form and button like:

```
<form>
  <input type="button" value="Add textbox" name="add" id="add"/>
</form>
```

then use [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method in `script` tags:

```
 var r;
$(function(){
    $('#add').on('click',function(){

        for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
       r= $('<input type="text" value="textbox" id="i"/>');
        }
        $("form").append(r);
    });
});
```

here, `<input type="text" value="textbox"/>` is taken as variable and then `appended` to the `form`.

[**DEMO FIDDLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/krupal/SP8de/40/).

Hi, [Here is exactly that you wanted.](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-add-remove-textbox-dynamically-with-jquery/)

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if a loop is possible for this, so that I can as many textboxes as I want.

Comment: @eljon_i3 you don't want to add textbox on a button click?

Comment: And when I add textboxes, how can I have different ID's on those textboxes? I'm really confused about this.

Comment: @eljon_i3 then you want to generate different textboxes with different IDs within the loop? sure?

Comment: @eljon_i3 please respond quickly..I am not free for you right now.

Comment: Yep that's exactly what I want. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: No problem, take your time. Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks! This is great, my bad for not accepting your answer though. Haha! Thanks so so much!

Comment: I'm sorry to disturb you again, but the loop isn't working, all of the textbox's ID that's generated were all equals to "i". I hope your still there..

Comment: @eljon_i3 i am sorry..I have tried everything as much I know..genuinely, you can unaccept my answer.

Comment: Are you there sir? I've managed to get the value of the i in the jquery, the problem is now, it isn't looping, all the value of the i is directed to 9 it's supposed to be 0-9 right?

Comment: @eljon_i3 Hi..I found this resource on internet..It matches exactly you want..: http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-add-remove-textbox-dynamically-with-jquery/

Comment: Thank you so much! You're such a big help.